# how to select specify with the first character in a column in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to select all the rows with contain with first number 1 from those rows as below data in image

```
$data = Modales::where('type', 5)->where('code', 'like', '%1%')->get();
```

[image]

Comment: $data = Modales::where('type', 5)->where('code', 'like', '1%')->get(); remove the first % so it will only watch for things with 1<and then anything>

Comment: but I want only the first character? so it is ok?

Comment: That's why you remove the first % - the percent means "here can be anything placeholder". If you have %1% then everything that has a 1 anywhere will match. If you have 1% then you match to everything that starts with a 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather oddly asked, but I am gathering from your comments that you want to query the table where a fields contains (and first character) matches your query, and then you only want to retrieve the first character of a specific field.

So, for instance:

```
Table Users

id | type     | name
1  | admin    | Patrick
2  | standard | Lucas
3  | standard | Anna
```

Then you would write your Eloquent query:

```
$users = User::where('type', 'LIKE', $char . '%')
    ->selectRaw('*, LEFT (name, 1) as first_char')
    ->get();
```

Then if `$char` = "s", then `first_char` would contain the first character of Lucas and Anna.

Comment: Thanks,
Sorry for badly english

Comment: well, that would be an alias in the SQL-query. `name` is the actual field you want the first character from.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use just like this:

```
->where($field, 'LIKE', $letter.'%');
```

Comment: Is it ok if I want only the first of those characters?
only the first one and number1